# faster and efficent alternative of pd.pivot_table of pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
def normalize_data(data):
   df_matrix = pd.pivot_table(data, values='purchase_count', index='customerId', columns='productId')
   df_matrix_norm = (df_matrix-df_matrix.min())/(df_matrix.max()-df_matrix.min())
   d = df_matrix_norm.reset_index()
   d.index.names = ['scaled_purchase_freq']
   return pd.melt(d, id_vars=['customerId'],value_name='scaled_purchase_freq').dropna()
```

the above code works fine but very slow and gives memory error when i increase size of data.
data is a dataframe that contain customerId , productId and purchase_count means how many times a product bought by each customer.

```
customerId,productId,product_count
21,24186,1
28,25949,1
31,12962,1
31,26246,1
38,26683,1
43,1667,1
50,10831,1
54,47752,1
63,47672,1
64,35108,1
71,48953,1
75,26882,1
77,11777,1
90,32648,1
91,33754,1
```

Required output by df_matrix (Normalize purchase history between 0 to 1)

```
    customerId productId  scaled_purchase_freq
    9   0   0.133333
    25  0   0.133333
    33  0   0.133333
    36  0   0.133333
    44  0   0.133333
```

Required output is just an sample.
I need help to find more efficient way to normalize the data.

Comment: try: `df.set_index(['customerId', 'productId'])['product_count'].unstack('productId')`

Comment: If it does not work, you should simply divide the dataframe, pivot and then concatenate

Comment: I'm sorry, i have missed complete information of question,  editing my question

Comment: please check question again